# Replacing a random string sequence with underscore

Tags: c#, string, replace

I was working on string manipulation, actually this string is stored in database in this format.

> THExaBROWNxbFOXxcJUMPSxdOVER

I need it in the format

> The_Brown_Fox_Jumps_Over

.

I was thinking of the sring replace method but this wont work.

```
string myString = "THExaBROWNxbFOXxcJUMPSxdOVER";
mystring = mystring.Replace("x", "_");
```

This one is bit tricky. need some help

Comment: What is the actual format? Is the separator xa for the first space, then xb for the second, xc for the third and so on?

Comment: or may be .split('match').join('replace'), these are all what i am trying but could not reach the solution.

Comment: The x char is always followed by a single char that should be removed together with the x?

Comment: @dotnetom Yes that is a two character format.The first one is fixed but the second one is a random like xa,xb,xc,x1,xj,xo,xb and so on.
I am really struck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex

```
string myString = "THExaBROWNxbFOXxcJUMPSxdOVER";
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"x\w", "_");
Console.WriteLine(myString);
```

This works only for a lowercase x followed by one and only one character

Without Regex

```
int pos = -1;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(myString);
while((pos = myString.IndexOf("x")) != -1)
{
    sb.Remove(pos, 2);
    sb.Insert(pos, "_");
    myString = sb.ToString();
}
Console.WriteLine(myString);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. if i change the string with  "THcExaBROcWNxbFcOXxcJUMPSxdOVERxbABCxmCOOL" it is giving me the desired result. But cant it be done without regex way ?? cause I have to again work on the other part also. which is to make the first character Uppercase immediately after the underscore and converting the other character to lower case.

Comment: Steve, OP had a new requirement as told in above comment, so I had to change my regex to yours. I hope you don't mind it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex here:

```
var str = Regex.Replace(input, "x\w", "_");
```

The above replaces group of small characters with `_`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.but if i alter the text by  "THcExaBROcWNxbFcOXxcJUMPSxdOVERxbABCxmCOOL" it is giving me completely new result which is bit unexpected.

Comment: Well, you didn't include that test case. I've updated